# How to safely stream data through a server socket to another socket?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, xamarin.ios, asyncsocket

I'm writing a server application for an iPhone application im designing. iPhone app is written in C# (MonoTouch) and the server is written in C# too (.NET 4.0)

I'm using asynchronous sockets for the network layer. The server allows two or more iPhones ("devices") to connect to each other and be able to send data bi-directionally.
Depending on the incoming message, the server either processes the message itself , or relays the data through to the other device(s) in the same group as the sending device. It can make this decision by decoding the header of the packet first, and deciding what type of packet it is.

This is done by framing the stream in a way that the first 8 bytes are two integers, the length of the header and the length of the payload (which can be much larger than the header).

The server reads (asynchronously) from the socket the first 8 bytes so it has the lengths of the two sections. It then reads again, up to the total length of the header section.

It then deserializes the header, and based on the information within, can see if the remaining data (payload) should be forwarded onto another device, or is something that the server itself needs to work with.
If it needs to be forwarded onto another device, then the next step is to read data coming into the socket in chunks of say, 1024 bytes, and write these directly using an async send via another socket that is connected to the recipient device.

This reduces the memory requirements of the server, as i'm not loading in the entire packet into a buffer, then re-sending it down the wire to the recipient.

However, because of the nature of async sockets, I am not guaranteed to receive the entire payload in one read, so have to keep reading until I receive all the bytes. In the case of relaying onto its final destination, this means that i'm calling BeginSend() for each chunk of bytes I receive from the sender, and forwarding that chunk onto the recipient, one chunk at a time.

The issue with this is that because I am using async sockets, this leaves the possibility of another thread doing a similar operation with the same recipient (and therefore same final destination socket), and so it is likely that the chunks coming from both threads will get mixed up and corrupt all the data going to that recipient.
For example: If the first thread sends a chunk, and is waiting for the next chunk from the sender (so it can relay it onwards), the second thread could send one of its chunks of data, and corrupt the first thread's (and the second thread's for that matter) data.

As I write this, i'm just wondering is it as simple as just locking the socket object?! Would this be the correct option, or could this cause other issues (e.g.: issues with receiving data through the locked socket that's being sent BACK from the remote device?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to accept the fact that sockets are shared across threads and send a streamID and streamOrderPosition along with each chunk. That way your application level protocol can take care of adding the chunks to the correct "stream" and at the correct position. Currently you are assuming that packets arrive in order, right? Though, doing what i propose may add too much overhead to your protocol.

Comment: Omitted the fact that I'm using tcp. So yes, I am assuming ordered packets as tcp is supposed to guarantee this (right?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, i've realised the simpliest approach is to use synchronous send commands on the client, or at least a send command that must complete before the next item is sent. Im handling this with my own send queue on the client, rather than various parts of the app just calling send() when they need to send something.

Comment: I have found that I need to write to the socket in a single place in the code. If it can be accessed by multiple threads, and I need to perform multiple write operations (eg: Socket.Send(messageLengthPrefix) followed by Socket.Send(messageBytes) ) I need to wrap it in a lock statement. Once thats done it solves any issues I was encountering.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar scenario a while back, I don't have the complete solution anymore, but here's pretty much what I did :

- I didn't use sync sockets, decided to explore the async sockets in C# - fun ride
- I don't allow multiple threads to share a single resource unless I really have to
- My "packets" were containing information about size, index and total packet count for a message
- My packet's 1st byte was unique to signify that it's a start of a message, I used 0xAA
- My packets's last 2 bytes were a result of a CRC-CCITT checksum (ushort)
- The objects that did the receiving bit contained a buffer with all received bytes. From that buffer I was extracting "complete" messages once the size was ok, and the checksum matched
- The only "locking" I needed to do was in the temp buffer so I could safely analyze it's contents between write/read operations

Hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem is. Since you mentioned servers, I assume TCP, yes?

A phone needs to communicate some of your PDU to another phone.  It connects as a client to the server on the other phone.  A socket-pair is established.  It sends the data off to the server socket.  The socket-pair is unique - no other streams that might be happening between the two phones should interrupt this, (will slow it up, of course).

I don't see how async/sync sockets, assuming implemented correctly, should affect this, either should work OK.

Is there something I cannot see here?

BTW, Maciek's plan to bolster up the protocol by adding an 'AA' start byte is an excellent idea - protocols depending on sending just a length as the first element always seem to screw up eventually and result in a node trying to dequeue more bytes that there are atoms in the universe.

Rgds,
Martin

OK, now I understand the problem, (I completely misunderstood the topology of the OP network - I thought each phone was running a TCP server as well as client/s, but there is just one server on PC/whatever a-la-chatrooms).  I don't see why you could not lock the socket class with a mutex, so serializing the messages.  You could queue the messages to the socket, but this has the memory implications that you are trying to avoid.

You could dedicate a connection to supplying only instructions to the phone, eg 'open another socket connection to me and return this GUID - a message will then be streamed on the socket'.  This uses up a socket-pair just for control and halves the capacity of your server :(

Are you stuck with the protocol you have described, or can you break your messages up into chunks with some ID in each chunk?  You could then multiplex the messages onto one socket pair.

Another alternative, that again would require chunking the messages, is introduce a 'control message', (maybee a chunk with 55 at start instead of AA), that contains a message ID, (GUID?), that the phone uses to establish a second socket connection to the server, passes up the ID and is then sent the second message on the new socket connection.

Another, (getting bored yet?), way of persuading the phone to recognise that a new message might be waiting would be to close the server socket that the phone is receiving a message over.  The phone could then connect up again, tell the server that it only got xxxx bytes of message ID yyyy.  The server could then reply with an instruction to open another socket for new message zzzz and then resume sending message yyyy.  This might require some buffering on the server to ensure no data gets lost during the 'break'.   You might want to implement this kind of 'restart streaming after break' functionality anyway since phones tend to go under bridges/tunnels just as the last KB of a 360MB video file is being streamed :(  I know that TCP should take care of dropped packets, but if the phone wireless layer decides to close the socket for whatever reason...

None of these solutions is particularly satisfying.  Interested to see whay other ideas crop up..

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: actually the 0xAA bit hails from a protocol that I'm familiar with, called IEEE C37.188

Comment: Imagine this is a chat server maintaining chatrooms of iPhone users.
User1 is sending a message is 256bytes, but accidently double taps the send button, sending 2 messages (using BeginSend) down the networkstream. The messages arrive in 64byte chunks, but because of network latency, the first chunk of msg1 arrives first, but then the 1st and second chunk of message 2 arrives between this and the 2nd and subsequent chunks of msg1. This would cause corruption. Im thinking now the only way is to use a ManualResetEvent per socket to limit **sending** to 1 thread at a time.

Comment: OK, now I understand - only one server, not a TCP server and possibly multiple clients on each phone.  Hmm.. need to think more about that!  Whatever happens, try very, very hard not to use simple events, especially manual-reset ones, for sync. Use crit section, mutex or semaphore.